# is there a solution for the installation of import 'package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart';

Tags: flutter, speech-to-text

I'm building a Speech to text app but when I try to import the library `speech_to_text`, I'm facing to that message unused import `package:speech_to_text/speech_to_text.dart`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it means that its not used yet. continue creating the code and when you use the tts, the warning will go away.